# Is it possible to make `ReplaySubject` to run a closure on being subscribed to?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I want to create a cold observable that would only start doing expensive operation if there is an actual subscription.  `ReplaySubject` would fit nicely except for the part that I need to be able to start an expensive background operation when the actual subscription is made and not on create of the observable.  Is there a way to do so?  Some sort of `onSubscribed { ... }` method.

Comment: Couldn't you use a `doOn` on the observable? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html

Comment: `doOn` are triggered when the observable is already hot, that is, producing the events.  If I were to use `doOn` to _start_ producing events then that would never work.

Comment: Yea, but that's what your question is asking for. Only perform some operation upon subscription. i.e. When your cold observable is starting.  He wasn't suggesting that you only use `doOn`, but `doOn` and then the eventual `subscribe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

Adding the expensive operation to a `doOn(onSubscribe:)` that's in between the `Observable` and the subscription:

```
let observable = Observable.of(1, 2)
    .doOn(onSubscribe: { _ in
        expensiveOperation()
    })

observable
    .subscribeNext { e in
        print(e)
    }
```

Making the `Observable` connectable and separating the `doOn(onSubscribe:)`:

```
let observable = Observable.of(1, 2)
    .publish()

observable
    .doOn(onSubscribe: { _ in
        expensiveOperation()
    })
    .subscribe()

observable
    .subscribeNext { e in
        print(e)
    }

observable.connect()
```

Comment: Sorry, but my instance of RxSwift does not have `doOn(onSubscribe:)` method.  If I try to use it I get an error: `extraneous argument label 'onSubscribe:' in call .doOn(onSubscribe: { _ in ...`  I use 2.6.0.  Which version you are on?

Comment: This is in 3.0.0.alpha.1, which if you can't use, then maybe use the "connectable" method, except don't use doOn, but rather just wrap the connect call in a method where you also make a call to your expensive method.

Comment: I moved to 3.0.0.beta.1 (and XCode 8 GM) and it now works as expected.  Thanks for the suggestion.